# How to create this column for Dates that are 5/24 - 27/41? MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to create this table: https://gyazo.com/7077635ffc81ee947cd7abf3725b0d8f

[image]

However, I can't seem to get the date to work.

This is what I have

```
CREATE TABLE Battles(
name VARCHAR(30), date DATE)


CREATE TABLE Battles(
name VARCHAR(30), date DATE);

INSERT into Battles VALUES
('Denmark Strait', 5/24 - 27/41),
('Guadalcanal', 11/15/42),
('North Cape', 12/26/43),
('Surigao Strait', 10/25/44);
```

It errors for the second part.

ERROR is

> Error Code: 1292. Incorrect date value: '-0.450203252' for column
>   'date' at row 1

How to fix?

Comment: You're doing division for the date values. What are you trying to insert?

Comment: What sort of date is `5/24 - 27/41` supposed to be?

Comment: I'm just trying to replicate this table but I'd assume its 1924 to 1941 since the other tables have 1900 dates. month/day/year

Comment: @OP: it seems, dates displayed are for view purpose only. actual formats must be different. mysql supports only `yyyy-mm-dd` format by default. you better convert the data you have to the supported format and then insert.

Comment: I'd sooner assume it is the range May 24 1941 - May 27 1941 ([Battle of Denmark Strait](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Battle_of_the_Denmark_Strait)). And the correct way to model that is to use a start and end date column. Where, if the range is a single date, you populate both with the same value.

Comment: I don't really care for the format of dates like 'yyyy-mm-dd', I just want it to be DATE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in SQL, columns with `DATE` datatype cannot be combined without converting them into `VARCHAR` datatype. So, the actual data is something like this :

```
|           name |       date |
|----------------|------------|
| Denmark Strait | 1941-05-27 |
| Denmark Strait | 1941-05-24 |
|    Guadalcanal | 1942-11-15 |
|     North Cape | 1943-12-26 |
| Surigao Strait | 1944-10-25 |
```

So, there are two records for Denmark Strait, and in the picture you provided is the results of merging the dates with the same names as `VARCHAR` without changing or touching the source (just formatting the output)

So, basicaly, you want to do the same process to acheive the same output.
You can do something like this :

```
SELECT 
    b1.name AS Name, 
    IF(COUNT(b1.name) > 1, CONCAT(DATE_FORMAT(b1.date, '%m/%d'), " - ", DATE_FORMAT(b2.date, '%d/%y')), CONCAT(DATE_FORMAT(b1.date, '%m/%d/%y')) ) AS Date
FROM battles b1
LEFT OUTER JOIN battles b2 ON b2.name = b1.name AND b2.date > b1.date
GROUP BY b1.name
```

OUTPUT

```
|           Name |          Date |
|----------------|---------------|
| Denmark Strait | 05/24 - 27/41 |
|    Guadalcanal |      11/15/42 |
|     North Cape |      12/26/43 |
| Surigao Strait |      10/25/44 |
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/79172f/1)